# Error with Query from the System Table

Tags: c#, .net

I want ask you one problem that I have with one query to the System table.
This is the code that I have wrong.

```
string current_query = "*[(System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime > '" + dateini + "']]) and (System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime &lt; '" + datenext + "']])]";
Console.WriteLine(current_query);

EventLogQuery eventsQuery = new EventLogQuery(log_location, PathType.FilePath, current_query);
EventLogReader logReader = new EventLogReader(eventsQuery);
```

The dateini and datenext are DateTime variables.I think that the problem is that I read the table two times. But I need read two times because I need obtain the logs of the System of one full day and I think I must compare between two System Times.

Any suggestion that how remake the consult.

UPDATE:
I try this query with the same result.

```
string current_query = "*[(Event/System/TimeCreated/@SystemTime > " + dateini + ") and   (Event/System/TimeCreated/@SystemTime &lt; " + datenext + ")]";
Console.WriteLine(current_query);

EventLogQuery eventsQuery = new EventLogQuery(log_location, PathType.FilePath, current_query);
EventLogReader logReader = new EventLogReader(eventsQuery);
```

Please I need help because I don't know which is the error in the Query.

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: Exception not controlled: System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogException: the specified consult is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TimeCreated is of the form:

```
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-08-15T16:21:21.000000000Z" />
```

is your datetime correct?

Shouldn't the query be more like:

```
Event/System/TimeCreated/@SystemTime
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb671197%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [reading-event-logs-efficiently-using-c](http://brijbhushan.net/2013/10/04/reading-event-logs-efficiently-using-c/) for some examples.

**EDIT**

Why are you using > and lt; ? Change lt; to <

This turned out to be the problem.

Comment: My DateTime is correct with the same lenght of characters.

Comment: I have updated my first post. Please I need more help. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: @JoseM. Why are you using > and lt; ? Change lt; to < . If that doesn't fix it try just this (System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime > xs:dateTime("2014-02-16T12:00:00")]]

Comment: Ok that was the problem I used &lt; because I have been using this query in an app config file with xml style. Thanks for your help but I have another mistake that I will open in another thread.

Comment: @JoseM. Your welcome, please mark this post as the answer so your question doesn't get added to the unanswered pile of posts, and of course so i get some juice ;)